# Drupal Captcha not working in panel

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

We are developing one site that is related to Health. and we need captcha for our whole site, so in that case we are using https://www.drupal.org/project/captcha module but that is not working on our panel page that is http://staging.vnahg.org/contact-us

Captcha is working other page but not on contact us related page.

So can you please help us to resolve this issue! because its not working and its already taken lots of time.

Comment: I have also try to active by hook_form_alter but not display array in the form control. one more question is can I achieve by hook_panel_alter?

Comment: You need to enable it for each form ID.

Comment: thanks Brian for giving such kind information it works